# Can we load only those classes which we have annotated with our custom annotation?

Tags: java, annotations

I came across one question regarding custom annotation.
Question :- 
Suppose we have created a custom annotation, and we applied it to some classes(Suppose in our application/module we have total of 10 classes, and we have applied custom annotation only on 5 classes, rest 5 are annotated with normal inbuilt annotation like @Autowiring, @COmponent and many more) in our app.

Now, when I load the whole application, will it be possible to load or we can say instantiate only those classes which I have annotated with my custom annotation.

Will it be possible?

Comment: With the term `loading`, do you mean the Java Class Loader? You also use the term `instantiate`, which has a total different meaning than `loading`.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming

```
@MyAnnotation
public class MyClass {
   ...
}
```

Then

```
if (MyClass.class.isAnnotationPresent(MyAnnotation.class)) {
   MyClass myObj = MyClass.newInstance();
}
```

Will conditionally instantiate an annotated class.

Comment: if (MyClass.isAnnotationPresent(MyAnnotation.class)) {
   MyClass myObj = MyClass.newInstance();
}
Do we have to create any separate class for this code or do we have any config class where we can do this?

Comment: this is a regular java code. any class that can import `MyClass` and `MyAnnotation` can do this. (providing  `MyClass` has no arg constructor)

Answer (score 0):

using entryClass.getAnnotation() we can load the class which we custom annotated.
`String jarFile = "path/to/jarfile.jar";
DexClassLoader classLoader = new DexClassLoader(
    jarFile, "/tmp", null, getClass().getClassLoader());
Class<?> myClass = classLoader.loadClass("MyClass");`

Comment: DexClassLoader only exists in Android